# Should we use "marŝi" or "paŝi" for "to walk"?

Tags: word-choice

I often see people use *marŝi* for walking. According to PIV, the first meaning of *marŝi* is military marching. There is also a second meaning which is similar to walking, which I found weird since there is already a word from the Fundamento for that: *paŝi*. There are also examples from Zamenhof where he uses *marŝi* instead of *paŝi*. Are those errors that became canon?

> *marŝ/i (ntr)
>
> - 1 Iri per egalaj paŝoj, kiel soldatoj, sportistoj, solenantoj ks: unue marŝis la luktistoj. poste la diskoĵetantoj; ekmarŝis la procesioZ; estas kvar, kiuj marŝas bele: […] leono […], cervo […], virkapro […] k reĝoX; takte marŝi. ☞ defili, paradi.
> - 2 Paŝadi iom longan vojon, por promeno aŭ alicele: sur la trotuaro marŝis paro da homoj, viro k virinoZ; ili marŝis per paŝoj facilaj k rapidajZ; sekvu min pluen sur la vojo, sur kiu marŝas la malgaja figuro de malriĉa virinoZ.

Here is the definition for *paŝi* from PIV:

> *paŝ/i (ntr)
>
> - Meti la piedojn alterne unu antaŭ alia, por sin transloki: rapide, sencele, takte paŝi; li maltime paŝis renkonte al ambaŭZ; la knabino, kiu paŝis sur panon, por ne malpurigi siajn ŝuojnZ; ili paŝis for silenteK; li paŝas rapide tien k reenZ; al la estrado en la mezo de la sinagogo malrapide paŝis la kantoro kun la sankta libroZ. ☞ iri, marŝi.

How should I translate *I prefer to walk*? What kind of translation is preferable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main choices for "walk" are:

- *iri* to go. In some contexts it may be easy to guess that you walked.
- *piediri* to go on foot. Specifying that you walked. (This is the best choice for your last question.)
- *promeni* to go for a walk. Recreational.
- *ekskursi* to hike.
- *paŝi* to take steps. Any situation in which you want to evoke the image of a short walk, a few steps being taken.
- *marŝi* to walk steadily. There are other, more specific terms for a military march (*defilo* or public *parado*) so this can confidently be used for any steady walk. Zamenhof used it too frequently in that manner for it to be a mistake; see for example his translation *Marta*. *("Apenaŭ ni komencis marŝi per niaj propraj infanaj piedoj...")*

You may also consider: *pasumi* stroll, *vagi* rove, *migri* wander.

A person in a *rulseĝo* ("wheelchair") *rulas [la seĝon] de loko al loko* ("rolls [the chair] from place to place"). You can also say *ruli sin* if it is clear what is meant, and I suppose *ruliri* would work although I haven't seen it used.

Comment: Piediri would be my choice for this as well.

Comment: It's questionable as to whether "hike" is properly expressed as "ekskursi." See this question for additional information. http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/hiking-in-esperanto

Answer (score 6):

That might depend on the context, but for *I prefer to walk* I'd say *Mi preferas piediri*.

Whether *marŝi* and *paŝi* are good translations for *to walk*, I am not sure. I agree with you, that the first relates to marching. And the other I suggest is closer to *stepping*.