# What are the differences between word roots for "walking"

Tags: word-meaning

In order to say, "to walk" or "a walk" (noun) there seem to be different roots: marŝi (marŝo), promeni (promeno? or promenado?), piediri (noun?). Could someone please clarify the differences? e.g. Is each used in different cases or could all of them in some form describe e.g. a walk in the park?

Comment: Welcome! Please change the title to an explicit question, such as "What are the different ways to say "to walk" or "a walk"?". Note that your topic may be closed if the question is considered too similar to this one: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/526/should-we-use-mar%C5%9Di-or-pa%C5%9Di-for-to-walk/532#532

Answer (score 4):

The [answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/526/should-we-use-mar%C5%9Di-or-pa%C5%9Di-for-to-walk/532#532) has been given to a [similar question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/526/should-we-use-mar%C5%9Di-or-pa%C5%9Di-for-to-walk) by Andrew Woods:

> The main choices for "walk" are:
>
> - *iri* to go. In some contexts it may be easy to guess that you walked.
> - *piediri* to go on foot. Specifying that you walked. (This is the best choice for your last question.)
> - *promeni* to go for a walk. Recreational.
> - *ekskursi* to hike.
> - *paŝi* to take steps. Any situation in which you want to evoke the image of a short walk, a few steps being taken.
> - *marŝi* to walk steadily. There are other, more specific terms for a military march (*defilo* or public *parado*) so this can confidently be used for any steady walk. Zamenhof used it too frequently in that manner for it to be a mistake; see for example his translation *Marta*. *("Apenaŭ ni komencis marŝi per niaj propraj infanaj piedoj...")*
>
> You may also consider: *pasumi* stroll, *vagi* rove, *migri* wander.
>
> A person in a *rulseĝo* ("wheelchair") *rulas [la seĝon] de loko al loko* ("rolls [the chair] from place to place"). You can also say *ruli sin* if it is clear what is meant, and I suppose *ruliri* would work although I haven't seen it used.

Comment: See the following question for additional clarifications on "hiking" and *ekskursi*. http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/hiking-in-esperanto