# Cxu "migrado" povas signifi "montmarsxado"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Marsxi gxis la pinto de monto povas esti unufoja aventuro por kelkaj kaj sxatokupo por aliaj. Mi rimarkis ke kelkaj homoj uzas "migrado" pri cxi tiu ago. Tiu vorto pensigas min pri homoj kiuj fugxas el siaj landoj, ne pri natura turismo. Cxu mi malpravas? Se ne, cxu estas alia taugxa vorto por "montmarsxado"?

In English: This question asks what "hiking" is in Esperanto.

Answer (score 4):

Montara aŭ mont(o)- marŝado / piedirado / paŝado / padmarŝado / padirado / padumado.

Rilata vorto: alpismo, montogrimpado.

Mi ne scias ĉu *monta migrado* estas vaste uzata en esperantujo kaj ĝi donas al mi la saman impreson kiel al vi pri translokado de homoj alilanden.

Answer (score 4):

"Migrado" ŝajnas al mi iom stranga en tiu kunteksto. Antaŭnelonge mi aŭdis ke "ekskursi" havas tiun sencon. Mi ankaŭ diras "marŝi" aŭ "marŝi en arbaro."

Answer (score 3):

*(monto)migrado* estas, kontraŭe al la ĝisnunaj respondoj, trafa kaj bona esprimo por "hiking".

Kvankam la difinoj en PIV povus sugesti ion alian, ĉe 'promeni' temas pri senstreĉa paŝado, ekz. tra parko, dum ĉe 'migri' pri bone preparita, peniga kaj pli longa marŝado, ekz. tra la montoj. Tiel klare montras la Zamenhofa (kaj alia) lingvouzo trovebla en la Tekstaro:

> *kaj tial li ekmigris pluen trans la altajn potencajn* montojn (Fabeloj de Anderson)
>
> *ili ne supreniris la ruĝan turon, ne promenis en la Frederikmonta parko* (Fabeloj de Anderson)

En germanaj montoj ĉiujare okazas Esperanta aranĝo nomata "Aŭtuna migrado".

Verŝajne por denaskaj parolantoj de la angla (kaj aliaj lingvoj) ŝajnas strange, ke la radiko MIGR' tradukas kaj "hike" kaj "migrate", sed tiu plursignifo estas ankaŭ en la germana kaj pola (mi ne scias pri la rusa) kaj tiel eniris Esperanton.

Answer (score 2):

**promeni**

*Iri de loko al loko por plezuro aŭ sano*: ili promenas ĉiam duope(Z). Vidu: **ekskursi**, **vagi**, **vojaĝi**. [Reta Vortaro]

Fakte **migri** havas iom saman difinon, tamen ankaŭ mencias ke oni ne uzu **migri** kaze de **promeni**.

```
promeni en la montaro = hike in the mountains
```

Do la sama nocio de korpa ekzercado kiel **hike**.