# Which verb should I use to translate “行万里路" (in Eng: "Walk ten thousand miles")?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I would like to translate the Chinese proverb "行万里路" to engrave on my birthday gift. It roughly means "walk ten thousand miles". The complete proverb is “读万卷书，行万里路"(Read ten thousand books, walk ten thousand miles), which implies that you have to go out and experience the real world, instead of only learning about life through books.

I started with "marŝu dekmil mejlojn", but I'm not sure if I should use "marŝu" or "piediru".

Comment: Mi proponas "trairu".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we use "marŝi" or "paŝi" for "to walk"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/526/should-we-use-mar%c5%9di-or-pa%c5%9di-for-to-walk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressing walking is surprisingly hard in Esperanto. You might want to take a look at the [answer by Andrew Woods](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/532/1872) here in Stack Exchange. In that answer he takes up the most common alternatives.

As Woods states *piediri* emphasises that you use your feet, not taking ,for instance, a car in order to go somewhere.

I cannot Chinese, but I began to wonder the miles in your translation. Doesn't one use kilometres, if not traditional units? Google makes a free translation of 读万卷书，行万里路 to *legu pli, marŝu pli*, i.e. take the trouble, struggle to achieve something. While you should always suspect Google, I agree with Google here, *marŝi* illustrates better the idea of struggling. If you want to include ten thousand (万), perhaps

> ***Legu dek mil librojn, marŝu dek mil paŝojn.***

Comment: Dek mil paŝoj ne estas multo, oni povas fari tion ene de unu tago... Dek mil libroj kaj dek mil kilometroj tamen... :-)

Comment: Jes mi scias, ke la rekomendo estis, ke oni tage piediru dek mil paŝojn (mi kredas, ke nuntempe oni diras, ke sufiĉas malpli). Miascie oni havas en Ĉinio, Koreio, Japanio kaj alie plurajn proverbojn, en kiuj oni uzas esprimon dek mil kiel priskribon por granda klopodo.

Answer (score 2):

For the translation of "to walk" you might check this question: [Should we use "marŝi" or "paŝi" for "to walk"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/526/should-we-use-mar%c5%9di-or-pa%c5%9di-for-to-walk?noredirect=1&lq=1). The currently accepted answer lists many options and explains the differences.

For the translation of the full idiom 读万卷书，行万里路: "read ten thousand books, walk then thousand miles", one way to translate is to consider that it is about learning (reading the books) and then using that knowledge in life (walking the world) [1](https://xyc2020.medium.com/we-have-a-saying-in-chinese-series-002-%E8%AF%BB%E4%B8%87%E5%8D%B7%E4%B9%A6-%E8%A1%8C%E4%B8%87%E9%87%8C%E8%B7%AF-7b0ab3eed436).

A couple of [nice translations](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%A1%8C%E4%B8%87%E9%87%8C%E8%B7%AF%EF%BC%8C%E8%AF%BB%E4%B8%87%E5%8D%B7%E4%B9%A6) from [chinese.yabla.com](https://chinese.yabla.com):

```
Knowledge comes from books and from experience of the world.

Learn as much as you can and do all you can.
```

In Esperanto I'd go with a known proverb, [for example this one](https://www.robkeetlaer.nl/esperanto/proverbaro/proverbo_002604.htm):

```
 Por sperto kaj lerno ne sufiĉas eterno
```

or [this one](https://www.robkeetlaer.nl/esperanto/proverbaro/proverbo_002049.htm):

```
 Vivu, progresu, sed lerni ne ĉesu
```

Alternatively, you could go with a simpler version like:

```
Vivu, lernu
Lernu, vivu
```

Answer (score 1):

Saluton!

Por komenco, la kvanto de libroj kaj vojoj ne gravas - ĉefa ideo estas, ke ili devas esti multaj kaj sufiĉaj por akiri sperton. Do, "multaj", "cent", "mil" aŭ "dek mil" havas egalan sencon.

读万卷书，行万里路. Por "libroj" - ni povas legi kaj studi. Kaj por "vojoj" - ni povas iri, marŝi, promeni kaj eĉ vojaĝi. Sed laŭ mia opinio, la ideo estas esprimi, ke la agoj devas esti plenumitaj kaj ĉefe rezulto-donaj. Do, tion ni povus emfazi per verboj tralegi kaj trairi/pasi/trapasi/travojaĝi.

Spertiĝu - tralegu mil librojn, trapasu mil vojojn!

Sed propono de Eduardo Trápani estas uzi ekzistantajn proverbojn - tio estas tre bona propono :)